# C++ basic setup for using openGL

Tags: c++, c

I have windows 8.1 OS. 
I wanted to run a basic C++ program using openGL so i downloaded a compatible Turbo C++ software of 64 bit.

When I run my program I got errors because it said `unable to open the header file i.e., graphics library`. Are there any primary things like setting up a path in environmental variables, which URL should I paste? Or let me also please know if there's any other common things that I need to set up in-order to use the Graphics Library. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Turbo C/C++ , Try any modern IDE (Codeblock , codelite , dev-c++ or any other). Read this 
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26

In IDE you will get all common header files plus examples , you will get an OpenGL example here . I suggest you to try codeblock.

Why not to use Turbo C/C++ (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962710/4499919)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL isn't suppported by `TC++`.

However you can run a simple `C` graphics program using `graphics.h`

Open `Options` and select `Directories` from it. 
[image]